# Link in InDesign CS6 with 'a href=' and 'rel='

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create a hyperlink or a button in inDesign that doesn't just link to one URL, but allows a 'rel=' parameter to be passed as well.

So instead of just a 'Go To Url' where you just put in the link address, you can put in something similar to 
`<a href="http://youtu.be/kh29_SERH0Y?rel=0" rel="lightbox" title="YouTube Video">` that can be clicked.